# Http digest authentication fails with jersey 2.x, works with curl

Tags: rest, http, post, jersey, digest-authentication

I am having trouble implementing a client for a http digest authenticated rest service. Using CURL i am able to call the service properly:

```
curl -v --digest -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @entity.json http://<server>:<port>/path
```

where entity.json contains a JSON structure of the entity object to be sent to the server

Using wireshark I can see the trace that a HTTP POST is sent, and a server response 401 authorized is received. A new post using the correct combination of md5 password nounce etc is sent and a 200 OK is received with a json response entity object. Everything is fine.

I have tried to implement this using jersey 2.x:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.client.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class RestApi
{
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestApi.class)

  private Client client;

  private String server;
  private String username;
  private String password;

  public RestApi(String server, String username, String password) {
    this.server = server;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public Client getClient() {
    if(this.client == null) {
      HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.digest(username, password);
      this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
      this.client.register(feature)
    }
    return this.client;
  }

  public <T> T post(
    final String path,
    final Object bodyValue,
    final Class<T> c) throws RestPostException {
    log.debug("POST path='{}', server='{}', bodyValue='{}'", path, server, bodyValue );

    WebTarget webTarget = getClient().target(server).path(path);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

    Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(bodyValue, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
      String errorString = response.readEntity(String.class);
      throw new RestPostException(
        "POST failed to '" + server + "/" + path + "' body value: '" + bodyValue + "' : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus() +
          ". Error string:" + errorString);
    }
    T retval = response.readEntity(c);
    return retval;
  }
}
```

The post method is called from another class like this:

```
String returnedValue = getRestApi().post(
  path,
  v,
  String.class);
```

where v is my json object to be sent in the request.

Tracing this with wireshark I see that the POST is sent (according to the trace the POST is exactly equal the one I send with curl), with a 401 unauthorized response. A new post is sent and I fail to get a 200 OK. Instead I get a new 401 Unauthorized.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Do you see any missing settings, configuration etc with the way I use the Java code?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get it work with "HttpAuthenticationFeature.digest".

But it works in standard apache http client way.
Below example of how to register CredentialsProvider with a dropwizard's JerseyClientBuilder:

```
    JerseyClientConfiguration configuration = config.httpClient;
    HttpHost target = HttpHost.create(config.apiUrl);
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(target), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(config.user, config.password));

    final Client httpClient = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment)
            .using(configuration)
            .using(credsProvider)
            .build("my-client");
```